# Change MagicMock return_value instance method callable to PropertyMock

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm trying to change the callable for an instance method on my `MagicMock` to a `PropertyMock` as that is how it is accessed (Django model column). But test fails with

```
 _mock_self = <PropertyMock name='get().my_prop' id='4524632776'>
```

Given the following code

```
# view
def get(self request):
    # stuff...
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=2)
    # more stuff...
    print(obj.my_prop)
    some_val = MyOtherModel(my_prop=obj.my_prop)

# tests
def test_my_test(mocker):
    other_obj = mocker.patch("app.views.MyOtherModel")
    obj_get = mocker.patch("app.views.MyModel.objects.get")
    obj_prop = mocker.PropertyMock(return_value=1)
    # This should translate to an instance of MyModel i.e. MyModel().my_prop
    obj_get.return_value.my_prop = obj_prop

    # run view

    obj_prop.assert_called_once() # Says never invoked
    # Failed as my_prop was a PropertyMock instead of actual value
    other_obj.assert_called_once_with(my_prop=obj_prop)
```

The print statement shows

```
 <PropertyMock name='get().my_prop' id='4524632776'>
```

So it appears it is the same instance it just is not actually being invoked

I also had attempted directly patching the property off the model but that does not appear to work as the `Mocks` are not the same.

```
def test_my_test(mocker):
    other_obj = mocker.patch("app.views.MyOtherModel")
    obj_prop = mocker.patch("app.views.MyModel.my_prop", new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)
    obj_get = mocker.patch("app.views.MyModel.objects.get")
    obj_get.return_value.my_prop = obj_prop

    # run view
    obj_prop.assert_called_once()
    # Failed as my_prop was a PropertyMock instead of actual value
    other_obj.assert_called_once_with(my_prop=obj_prop)
```

Which fails with...

```
_mock_self = <PropertyMock name='my_prop' id='4543022192'>
```

but prints

```
 <MagicMock name='get().my_prop' id='4543752232'>
```

**EDIT** Added in other patches that more accurately depicted the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the desired property with a `PropertyMock` was unnecessary as I could simply assigned the value I wanted to the `MagicMock`.

```
def test_my_test(mocker):

    other_obj = mocker.patch("app.views.MyOtherModel")

    obj_get = mocker.patch("app.views.MyModel.objects.get")
    obj_get.return_value.my_prop = 2

    # run view
    other_obj.assert_called_once_with(my_prop=obj_get.return_value.my_prop)
```

The `.assert_called_once` was used to check if the attribute was ever invoked and was added when an `.assert_called_once_with` originally failed.